# Infix To Prefix Mathematical Expression Converter in Java

Tags: java, math, expression, prefix

I am trying to write a method that converts Infix To Prefix Mathematical Expression and to do that I use a stack. But I get error in some cases and I do not know what is problem.

code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Prefixer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName;
        boolean reduce = false;
        if (args.length == 1){
            fileName = args[0];
        }
        else if (args.length >= 2){
            reduce = args[0].equals("-r");
            fileName = args[1];
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        BufferedReader reader;
        String line = "";
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (fileName));
            line = reader.readLine();
            line = line.trim();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(infixToPrefixConvert(line,reduce));
    }

    public static boolean isOperand(String s) {
        return !(s.equals("+") || s.equals("-") || s.equals("/") || s.equals("*") || s.equals("(") || s.equals(")"));
    }

    public static boolean isNumber(String s){
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
        } catch (Exception e){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static String operationCombine(Stack<String> operatorStack, Stack<String> operandStack, boolean reduce){
        String operator = operatorStack.pop();
        String rightOperand = operandStack.pop();
        String leftOperand = operandStack.pop();
        if (reduce && isNumber(rightOperand) && isNumber(leftOperand)){
            int left = Integer.parseInt(leftOperand);
            int right = Integer.parseInt(rightOperand);
            int result = 0;
            if (operator.equals("+")){
                result = left + right;
            }else if (operator.equals("-")){
                result = left - right;
            }else if (operator.equals("*")){
                result = left * right;
            }else if (operator.equals("/")){
                result = left / right;
            }
            return "" + result;

        }
        String operand = "(" + operator + " " + leftOperand + " "+ rightOperand + ")";
        return operand;
    }

    public static int rank(String s) {
        if (s.equals("+") || s.equals("-"))
            return 1;
        else if (s.equals("/") || s.equals("*"))
            return 2;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public static String infixToPrefixConvert(String infix, boolean reduce) {
        Stack<String> operandStack = new Stack<String>();
        Stack<String> operatorStack = new Stack<String>();

        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(infix);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
            if (isOperand(token)) {
                operandStack.push(token);
            }

            else if (token.equals("(") || operatorStack.isEmpty()
                    || rank(token) > rank(operatorStack.peek())) {
                operatorStack.push(token);
            }

            else if (token.equals(")")) {
                while (!operatorStack.peek().equals("(")) {
                    operandStack.push(operationCombine(operatorStack, operandStack,reduce));
                }
                operatorStack.pop();
            }

            else if( rank(token) <= rank(operatorStack.peek())){
                while(!operatorStack.isEmpty() && rank(token) <= rank(operatorStack.peek())){
                    operandStack.push(operationCombine(operatorStack, operandStack,reduce));
                }
                operatorStack.push(token);
            }
        }
        while( !operatorStack.isEmpty() ) {
            operandStack.push(operationCombine(operatorStack, operandStack,reduce));
        }
        return (operandStack.peek());
    }

}
```

The file should be the first line with the infix expression you want to convert.
The -r flag is used if you want to reduce simple arithmetic expressions as you convert 
to prefix.
for example in test.txt , if I have

```
3 * 9 + ( 9 + y ) / 4 - x
```

It work fine.
but if I have

```
12 / c + c * p ^ ( 8 + 9 )
```

it should give me : 
12 c / c p 8 9 + ^ * +
but I get :
(+ p (* ^ (+ 8 9)))

what is the problem. please help me.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just taking a glimpse on your code i could probably say that this line

```
String operand = "(" + operator + " " + leftOperand + " "+ rightOperand + ")";
```

Is the root of your problem, and the fact that you are not considering operator `^` in `operationCombine` function.